# Trigger an update on a column of a row if a select partially matches one of that row's columns

Tags: mysql

To be more clear:

The table *thetable* `(id int, username varchar(30), password varchar(30), last_successful_login timestamp, last_unsuccessful_login timestamp, another_variable varchar(30))` has the following row: (1, "tgh", "pass", 0, 0, "another")

**1) Wrong User/Pass Pair, but there is a row with the *username***

I want `select id from thetable where username="tgh" and password="wrongpass" and another_variable="another";` to update the `last_unsuccessful_login` columns of all the rows with `username="tgh"` AND `another_variable="another"` (which is unique, there can't be two rows with ("tgh", "another") pair. There can be ("tgh", "another2") though.) to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

So the example row would be `(1, "tgh", "pass", 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "another")`, **after the *"select"* query that *does not completely* match**.

To be even more clear, I am trying to avoid running an extra update with only `username="tgh"` and `another_variable="another"` on the table, i.e. `update thetable set last_unsuccessful_login=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where username="tgh" and another_variable="another";`, according to the result of the select.

**2) Correct User/Pass Pair**

Also, if all three `username` and `password` and `another_variable` matches, this time I want to set the `last_successful_login` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

That would make the example row `(1, "tgh", "pass", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, "another")

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What is your table structure? (the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE thetable`) What kind of trigger do you want: INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE ?

Comment: I think I have made everything clear in the question, including what you are asking.

Comment: You haven't. I don't post comments for fun. Your question does not say what your table structure is. And it is nearly impossible to understand what you want to do. Also, your question does not show clearly what you have tried. You have the right to refuse to update your question. But then, don't be surprised that nobody can help you or wants to help you.

Comment: @TolgaHoşgör: If I may add my 2 cents: I have really problems to understand your question. It might be because of the way you ask, because of the formatting, because of the irritating naming of the table and the columns and because of the lack of context which could clarify those points that are just plain ambiguous. I can understand you have a different opinion, however it's useless to neglect feedback given in comment by those who wanted to help you. Think about it.

Comment: `(id int, a int, b int, c timestamp, d timestamp, e)` this is the table structure and it is in the question.
However, I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: Okay, I managed to think of one solid example of real-world usage of what I needed. I think it the question seems way more complicated now.
Let me know if something is still not clear.

Comment: Kindly user meaningful names for tablename, columname so that its easy to read and answer.

Comment: @FirmView Yeah, I am trying to update timestamps according to the fact that login in successful or not, without using an extra `update` statement. I am asking if that is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, it is not possible for a SELECT statement to cause or trigger an update. (The caveat here is that a SELECT statement can call a FUNCTION (MySQL stored program) which can perform an UPDATE.)

You can't get around issuing an UPDATE statement; an UPDATE statement has to be issued from somewhere, and a SELECT statement cannot "trigger" it.

It is possible to have a single UPDATE statement do the check of the supplied password against the current value in the password column, and set both the last_successful_login and last_unsuccessful_login columns, e.g.:

```
UPDATE thetable 
   SET last_successful_login = 
       IF(IFNULL(password,'')='wrongpass',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,0)
     , last_unsuccessful_login = 
       IF(IFNULL(password,'')='wrongpass',0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 WHERE username='tgh' 
   AND another_variable='another'
```

So, you could issue an UPDATE statement first; and then issue a SELECT statement.

If you want to minimize the number of "roundtrips" to the database, at the cost of additional complexity (making it harder for someone else to figure out what is going on) you could put the UPDATE statement into a stored program. If you put this into a function, you could set the return value to indicate whether the login was successful.

```
SELECT udf_login('username','wrongpass','another')
```

So, from your application, it looks like you are doing a login check, but the called function can perform the UPDATE.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `udf_login`
( as_username         VARCHAR(30)
, as_password         VARCHAR(30)
, as_another_variable VARCHAR(30) 
) RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   UPDATE `thetable`
      SET `last_successful_login` = 
          IF(IFNULL(`password`,'')=IFNULL(as_password,''),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,0)
        , `last_unsuccessful_login` = 
          IF(IFNULL(`password`,'')=IFNULL(as_password,''),0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    WHERE `username` = as_username
      AND `another_variable` = as_another_variable;

   -- then perform whatever checks you need to (e.g)
   --     SELECT IFNULL(t.password,'')=IFNULL(as_password,'') AS password_match
   --       FROM `thetable` t
   --      WHERE t.username = as_username
   --        AND t.another_variable = as_another_variable
   -- and conditionally return a 0 or 1
   RETURN 0;
END$$
```

Comment: The second idea is great. The SQL server is on a remote machine. I know this is not a good idea but the authentication won't be performed _that_ often to start raising problems (if I could find a way to get rid of a few extra UPDATE statements of course). However, with your second approach, I can put a lot of things into one query, not only the UPDATE. Also, I assume it won't hog the database resources in general because there won't be some kind of trigger-checking on all queries. Thanks.

Comment: @Tolga: yes, if you have several SQL statements that need to run as a group, then including them together into a "stored program" in the MySQL database can be more efficient, because it can reduce the number of "roundtrips" between the client and the server. (NOTE: The `READS SQL DATA` is a kludge, to get around a MySQL error when creating the function, the function actually MODIFIES SQL DATA. You might actually want to call a stored procedure that uses an OUT argument to return a value.